# Unity doesn't build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a strange problem that I have never encountered before. I can't compile the build. The "Build and run" button is simply greyed out. There are no errors in the console. A clean build didn't help either. The game works in the Unity editor. I don't understand what the problem is at all. I tried rebooting and reinstalling the build, but Unity still stands its ground. I really need help. By the way, when I tried to rollback to previous versions using Git, it still didn’t help - even on older versions, when I made builds, it’s impossible to do now.

I'm using Unity 2021.3.9f1 and Windows 11. Any help would be helpful.

update: after numerous attempts, I still found the following 4 errors, but I still have no idea what to do about it, because it seems to me that everything is fine:

```
    1. error: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
    2. Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code -2146233088.
    error: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
    System.Exception: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
       at WinPlayerBuildProgram.WinPlayerPrerequisiteChecks.CheckSafeProjectOverwrite(PlayerBuildConfig playerBuildConfig)
       at WinPlayerBuildProgram.WinPlayerBuildProgram..ctor(String[] args)
       at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
       at Program.Main(String[] args)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
    3. BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
    UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
    UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
    UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.WinPlayerPostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinPlayer/Extensions/Managed/WinPlayerPostProcessor.cs:38)
    UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options , UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
    4. Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 25 seconds (25413 ms)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
    generalized: UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
      at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0 
      at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0 
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: well.. i assume you started a build and either it think its its still running, or you didnt install any outputs for unity (unlikely as it seems to think it was building), or as it says you tried to build it into a folder which contained something and you confused it, or maybe you have one drive/googledrive etc as that offends it.. or you have odd characters in your build path, it hates that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that a few times, and what i learned and do when that happens is:

-Try making a new folder, even inside your project if you want, name something like BuildVersions and try making a new one.

-Delete the .sln file from your project and try again.

-Disable the Visual Studio Solution option, build it, and then try again with it on.

These always worked out for me, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much buddy! That helped. I had a deadline coming up and I was terribly nervous, but now the problem is solved thanks to you!

Comment: Good to know, you're welcome.